# mySQL tips for beginner

Tags: mysql

```
PERSON
DriverID (primary)
DriverName
Address

CAR
RegNO (primary) 
Model 
Year

ACCIDENT
ReportNumber (primary)
AccidentDate
Location

OWNS
DriverID (primary key)  foreign key with PERSON(DriverID)
RegNo (primary Key) foreign key with CAR(RegNo)

PARTICIPATION
DriverID (primary key) foreign key with PERSON (DriverID)
RegNo (primary Key) foreign key with CAR(RegNo)
ReportNumber (primary key) foregin with ACCIDENT(primary)
Damage Amount
```

the query is -> find the no of accidents in which car belonging to a specific model were involved

the sol is

```
SELECT COUNT (a.ReportNumber)
FROM ACCIDENT a
WHERE
a.ReportNumber in ( SELECT pa.ReportNumber FROM PARTICIPATED pa, CAR c
WHERE pa.RegNo = c.RegNo AND c.Model = 'honda');
```

my question is how to understand complex queries involving nested queries 
in C++ u can use breakpoints to debug but how to debug in mySQL 
i use SQLyog and i know all basic query including GROUP
but when it nested queries comes i can't understand

Answer (score 0):

Run this query by itself:

```
SELECT pa.ReportNumber FROM PARTICIPATED pa, CAR c
WHERE pa.RegNo = c.RegNo AND c.Model = 'honda'
```

Look at the `reportnumbers` and keep them in the back of your mind.

Now run this query:

```
SELECT a.ReportNumber FROM ACCIDENT a
```

So, the first query gets you all of the report numbers in `participated` with a `'honda'` `car`. The second query gets you every `reportnumber` of all time in `accident`.

Put them together, and you get every `reportnumber` from `accident` who `participated` with a `'honda'`.

I hope this answers your question, I wasn't perfectly clear what you were asking.